# jQuery hide (and show) element within parent

Tags: jquery

OK, maybe it's late in the day! I've tried most the related questions, I'm sure it's pretty simple but here goes:

Here's the HTML structure:

```
<article>

<div class="info-wrap">
<p>blah blah</p>
<a href="#" class="info-close">Close div!</a>
</div>

<a href="#" class="info-show">Show div!</a>

</article>
```

There will be multiple instances of the above structure (Wordpress loop) so it should only show the div within that instance (not all of them). This is my jQuery so far:

```
$("a.info-show").click(function(){
     $(this).parent('article').find('.info-wrap').animate({ opacity: 'show' }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Not working. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Are the `.info-wrap` elements initially hidden in the sense of `display:none`? If so, just use `.fadeIn()`, which will do the animation you want as well as changing the `display` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.info-show").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('article').find('div.info-wrap').animate({ opacity: 1 }, "slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Or use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.info-show").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('article').find('div.info-wrap').fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Read http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ and http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: The 2nd one worked, but not the first. Don't know why, but thanks!

Comment: For that you have to change the opacity to `0 initially`, also for `fadeIn` you have to set the `property=display:none` initially.

Answer (score 1):

you can use example created like

```
$("a.info-show").click(function(e){

$(this).parents('article').find('.info-wrap').fadeIn('slow');
    $("a.info-show").hide('slow');
    return false;
});


$("a.info-close").click(function(e){

$(this).parents('article').find('.info-wrap').fadeOut('slow');
 $("a.info-show").show('slow');
    return false;
});
```

and use [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/liyakat/Fgs5Y/) to test your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script is running inside onready, other than that it seems fine.

```
$(function(){
    $("a.info-show").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.info-wrap').animate({ opacity: 'show' }, "slow");
        return false;
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HJQ6a/)

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
$("a.info-show").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest("article").find("div.info-wrap").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Also make sure that the classes are actually present when jquery initialises. If you are using ajax for this, it might be a good idea to `bind` these to a parent node

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. Only problem that i can think of is that you are not binding the click function to an event (like document.ready()). Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpsSj/) for you.

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.info-show').click(function(){
        var info = $(this).parent().find('.info-wrap > p');
        info.animate({ opacity: 1 }, "slow");
    });
    $('.info-close').click(function(){
        var info = $(this).parent().find('p');
        info.animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow");
    });
});
```

Also make sure you initially set the opacity to 0 for this to work.

#### CSS

```
article .info-wrap > p {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.prev()`:

```
$("a.info-show").click(function () {
   $(this).prev('.info-wrap').fadeIn();
   return false;
});
```

#### [checkout the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EpdVU/)